# Use service discovery to dispatch jobs with same ID to same worker node

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, consul, istio

(Apology in advance for the noob question; I have zero experience with DevOps.)

In my recent project I stumbled upon this problem that I don’t know if service discovery tools (such as Consul/Istio/etc.) can address.

Our use case is this: we have a VoIP app similar in idea to Discord. Users can join a voice channel and start talking. However, to forward the voice packets between users in a same voice channel, their WebRTC voice connections need to be handled by a same server process, so that we can process & forward all the voice packets in a voice channel in-memory.

In order to do this, we have a separate service (call it service X) in front of our voice service (service V) that receives a user request to join channel N, and based on N, assign a server in service V to the user. We need to guarantee that for the same channel N, X always picks the same server in V.

We implemented this in a non-scalable way just for quick prototyping. Now that we want to implement this properly, I’m wondering if tools like Consul/Istio/etc. can help us in this scenario. Is there a common approach to address this kind of problems?

Comment: Are you definitely using kubernetes to host or is that just another option? The requirements fall outside of the standard k8s service scaling and load balancing model. You might need to either lookup pod IP's directly or deploy a service per pod to be able to address a single instance of `V`. But you could lookup all that information from the k8s API from `X`. Then it needs some type of store to track the client -> `V` mapping

Comment: So how does k8s know which channel the request belongs? If your request use HTTP/HTTPS protocol, put your channel info into headers, and Istio can route the request by your custom strategy.

Comment: @menya The tricky part is this is not a standard HTTP(S) model. The user initiates a voice connection by first establishing a WebSocket connection to service `X` (for which session affinity doesn't matter), and service `X` needs to use the channel info sent through the initial WebSocket to notify a certain node in service `V` to start listening for a WebRTC connection, which isn't based on HTTP(S).

Comment: @Matt Kubernetes is not a hard requirement but it'd be nice if we can use it. Does not using K8s in anyway simplify the problem?

Comment: @ZizhengTai I think you need a external `LoadBalancer`, k8s internal load balance strategy is too naive.

Comment: @menya an external LoadBalancer doesn't disable the k8s internal load balancing from services to pods. You would also need to keep a 1 to 1 service to pod mapping, so no replicasets or scaling or do like the Ingress controllers for sticky sessions, and connect to the list of endpoints for the service, rather than the service IP itself.

Comment: @ZizhengTai k8s still might simplify your deployment and environment management, but you won't be able to use a lot of the standardised http stuff like an ingress controller with sticky sessions. Basically you will be writing a webrtc ingress controller that sticks a session to a static Service Endpoint, kubernetes will help you discover this info though

Answer (score 2):

Istio won't necessarily help you since it's more about [controlling traffic](Like you mentioned you can use Consul as a service discovery tool, or ). For example, doing canary deployment or applying security to your service. Quoted from the [docs](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#routing-subset):

> Istio doesn’t provide DNS resolution. Applications can try to resolve the FQDN by using the DNS service present in their platform of choice, for example kube-dns.

You can use the standard Kubernetes service discovery using [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). Or like you mentioned you can use Consul as a service discovery tool, the added benefit of using something like Consul is that since it's not Kubernetes specific you could potentially also use for services outside your Kubernetes cluster or in other Kubernetes clusters.

Since sounds like your initial connections come and go, it sounds like that in order to who joins what channel and what channel talks to what backend you will need to keep state somewhere like a database, or key-value store.

Comment: How would you satisfy the requirement that the same channel is always assigned the same voice node (at least the server can't change when there are still users in the voice channel)? My limited understanding is, service discovery tools such as Consul usually just give you an arbitrary healthy node that's not overloaded.

Comment: You might use `nodeSelector` or `nodeAffinity` or deploy `DeamonSet`.